# OpenGL object moving in a circle automaticlly

Tags: c++, opengl, undefined

Im trying to get my model to move around in a circle and im getting errors that loop and speed are undefined.my code is here and im providing 2 class files the header file and the .cpp file.

Header File

```
#ifndef OBJECTLOADERGUILTYSPARK_H
#define OBJECTLOADERGUILTYSPARK_H

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include "glut.h"
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include "StructHeader.h"

using namespace std;

class ObjectLoaderGuiltyspark
{
private:

string guiltyName;
int numVert;
int numNormals;
int numcoords;
int numFaces;
int ammount;
float speed;
point3D loop;
float radius;
point3D v343[1718];
point3D vn343[964];
point3D vt343[521];
point3Di f343[5186][3];


public:
ObjectLoaderGuiltyspark(string guiltyName);
~ObjectLoaderGuiltyspark() {};

void objLoader343(string guiltyName);
void draw343(int x, int y, int z, point3D loop[], int radius);
void getCalcPlanetCircle();
circle getPlanetPos();
   };

  #endif
```

class file

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "ObjectLoaderGuiltyspark.h"
#include <math.h>



ObjectLoaderGuiltyspark::ObjectLoaderGuiltyspark(string gName)
: guiltyName(gName)
{
numVert = 0;
numNormals = 0;
numcoords = 0;
numFaces = 0;
ammount = 0;
speed = 5;
radius = 5;
loop = new point3D[600];

}

void ObjectLoaderGuiltyspark::objLoader343(string gfile) 
{

string test;
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open(gfile);

if (!inputFile.good())
    cout << "Problem with Input File";
else
{
    while(inputFile >> test)
    {

        if (test == "v")
        {
            inputFile >> v343[numVert].x;
            inputFile >> v343[numVert].y;
            inputFile >> v343[numVert].z;
            numVert++;
        }

        else if(test == "vn")
        {
            inputFile >> vn343[numNormals].x;
            inputFile >> vn343[numNormals].y;
            inputFile >> vn343[numNormals].z;
            numNormals++;
        }
        else if(test == "vt")
        {
            inputFile >> vt343[numcoords].x;
            inputFile >> vt343[numcoords].y;
            inputFile >> vt343[numcoords].z;
            numcoords++;
        }
        else if(test == "f")
        {
            string temp;
            for(int count = 0; count < 3; count++)
            {   
                inputFile >> temp;
                stringstream stream(temp);

                getline(stream, temp, '/'); 
                f343[numFaces][count].x = atoi(temp.c_str()) - 1;
                getline(stream, temp, '/'); 
                f343[numFaces][count].y = atoi(temp.c_str()) - 1;
                getline(stream, temp, '/'); 
                f343[numFaces][count].z = atoi(temp.c_str()) - 1;
            }

            numFaces++;
        }


    }
}
}

void getCalcPlanetCircle(point3D loop[], int radius)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 600 ; i++)
        {
            loop[i].x = radius * sin(i/100.0);
            loop[i].y = 0;
            loop[i].z = radius * cos(i/100.0);
        }
}


circle getPlanetPos()
{
    circle loopPos;
    loopPos.xRot = loop[(int)(ceil (speed))].x;
    loopPos.yRot = loop[(int)(ceil (speed))].y;
    loopPos.zRot = loop[(int)(ceil (speed))].z;
    return loopPos;
}

void ObjectLoaderGuiltyspark::draw343(int x, int y, int z, point3D loop[], int radius)
{

glTranslated(loop[(int)(ceil (speed))].x, loop[(int)(ceil (speed))].y, loop[(int)            (ceil (speed))].z);

for(int i = 0; i < 5186; i++)//reads coords for verts from global arrays.
{

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    int one = f343[i][0].x;
    int two = f343[i][1].x;
    int three = f343[i][2].x;

    int tex_one = f343[i][0].z;
    int tex_two = f343[i][1].z;
    int tex_three = f343[i][2].z;

    glVertex3fv(&(v343[one].x));
    glTexCoord2fv(&(vt343[tex_one].x));
    glVertex3fv(&(v343[two].x));
    glTexCoord2fv(&(vt343[tex_two].x));
    glVertex3fv(&(v343[three].x));
    glTexCoord2fv(&(vt343[tex_three].x));


    glEnd();
}
}
```

Comment: well, have you included files with definition of point3d?

Comment: yes it compiles now, just to clarify it rendered before and a it was view able and i just wanted to make it move around a point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getPlanetPos is declared as a member function, but defined (implemented) as a free function.  You just need to prefix with ObjectLoaderGuiltyspark::

Comment: thanks it now compiles but i set the original pos to 0,0 and the radius to 2 but its not rendering or I cannot find it.